# error when scraping the google search result and prints it

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using Python 3.6 and BeautifulSoup is installed in my computer with:

```
pip install beautifulsoup
```

How can I treat this:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "I:\application
>   python\rechere1.py", line 5, in      from bs4 import
>   BeautifulSoup   File "I:\application python\bs4.py", line 3, in
>        from bs4 import BeautifulSoup ImportError: cannot import
>   name 'BeautifulSoup' >>>

Comment: Try `pip install beautifulsoup4`. See [the docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-beautiful-soup).

Comment: installed ,but when i run the code i get this error